# How can I pass the current line to a Vimscript function?

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a Vim mapping that will operate on the current line, taking a string like this:

```
[boiled cabbage, mad donkey, elephant, very dark fudge]
```

And quoting all the list elements to end up with this:

```
["boiled cabbage", "mad donkey", "elephant", "very dark fudge"]
```

I tried with vim regexes, but figured it would be easier to write a function that takes the current line as an argument and returns the transformed line.  I have no problem performing the transformation in vimscript.  But how can I pass the current line to the function, and how do I replace the line with the transformed line?

Comment: You question has been answered, but I recommend you take a look at `:help function-list`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To get current line you can use

```
let line=getline('.')
```

(note: you can also do `getline(10, 20)` to get a list of 11 lines).

To set current line you can use

```
call setline('.', line)
```

. You can also replace a number of lines starting with current if you pass a list to this function.

Answer (score 5):

You can yank it into a register and then access it from there. `"byy` yanks the line your cursor is at. You can access it then by using `@b`

Check out http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_under_cursor_for_command

Comment: shouldn't it be "byy rather than byy?